# On Topic - Off Topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I do understand that we are trying to build up the site but there was a question:

[When should I start looking for my first employment?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/519/when-should-i-start-looking-for-my-first-employment)

Which doesn't quite sit well with seeming intention of the site.  Is looking for your first job on-topic here?

Technically for example I could see "Taking my first job in the same place as I interned" might be on topic but this one is looking more on a career advice not related to the Workplace issues since there isn't one yet.  There were comments that we already have questions about interviewing:

[How to coordinate the process of pursuing multiple job opportunities at the same time?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-to-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-same)

But this one for example involves your current employer as well.

Comment: It seems this site should be a great resource for first time employees, I don't see any reason to exclude them particularly. It's a matter of navigating the professional setting.

Comment: @YannisRizos [what have I done!](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this site should be a great resource for first time employees, I don't see any reason to exclude them particularly.

It's a matter of navigating the professional setting, which is exactly what we have in the FAQ. They're not *yet* members of the workforce (another criteria in the FAQ) but I don't think it's fair to discount them.

Similar to how a retired worker might have some great insight to offer in answers, even if they're not current members of the workforce, first time job seekers might have some excellent questions.

In addition, the [hiring-process](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring-process) tag is the most used one on the site so far, so I think it's fair to say that many of us consider job-seeking things like that to be on topic as long as it's otherwise a good, constructive question.

Answer (score 2):

This SE basically encompasses anything you do at or related to work that does not involve a specific job's function.  This includes the process of getting a job, dealing with losing a job, and all that in between.  So long as it is specific in its intent so as not to require a novel, nor so limited that a one line answer is acceptable.

Off Topic

- Questions that are about performing a specific job(other than general management).
- Questions about law and legality specifically
- Questions asking for a list of resources.
- Questions that are [not about work at all](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/535/how-can-i-reduce-my-caffeine-addiction).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the two question you use as examples, they are about procedures related to job hunting.

- The first is by a college student with an internship who wants to find a paying job.
- The second is by a employee wanting to know how to leverage one company against another.

They would even more alike if the intern had asked the second question, and very well might once they start applying.

I believe that if the 2nd question in on topic, then the first is also.